# C++ build system [configure] failed while executing: [...] CXX1405 in android Kotlin

Tags: github

[CXX1405] error when building with cmake using C:\TUFEL\ANDROID STUDIO\Whatsapp\app\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt: C++ build system [configure] failed while executing:
@echo off
"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\cmake.exe" ^
"-HC:\TUFEL\ANDROID STUDIO\Whatsapp\app\src\main\cpp" ^
"-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android" ^
"-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON" ^
"-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=21" ^
"-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21" ^
"-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a" ^
"-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a" ^
"-DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620" ^
"-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620" ^
"-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake" ^
"-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\ninja.exe" ^
"-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\TUFEL\ANDROID STUDIO\Whatsapp\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\1f2m115u\obj\arm64-v8a" ^
"-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\TUFEL\ANDROID STUDIO\Whatsapp\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\1f2m115u\obj\arm64-v8a" ^
"-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ^
"-BC:\TUFEL\ANDROID STUDIO\Whatsapp\app\.cxx\Debug\1f2m115u\arm64-v8a" ^
-GNinja
from C:\TUFEL\ANDROID STUDIO\Whatsapp\app

I am encountering a **CXX1405 ** error while building a C++ project with CMake in Android Studio. Specifically, the error message states:

C++ build system [configure] failed while executing: [...] CXX1405

I have tried several solutions, including updating CMake and the Android NDK, setting the ANDROID_NDK_HOME environment variable, and cleaning and rebuilding the project. However, none of these solutions have resolved the issue.

In addition, I have noticed that the CMakeLists.txt file generates an empty CMakeLists.txt.marker file, and the CMakeLists.txt.tmp file contains a configure script with no content.

I am hoping to find a solution to this issue so that I can successfully build the project. Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

anyone can have an answer for this problem pleas tell me or message me on
my Telegram : https://t.me/malik_tufel_official

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Make sure to download and install Visual C++ from this [link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads) you will find it in the Other Tools, Frameworks, and Redistributables section.